# Find the transformation given 2 non standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation

[image]

For question (a) I can solve it by taking matrix A and multiplying it with each vector of bases B to find [T(vi)]_B'.

However, I'm confused on how to find T(v1) and so on.

What I tried was taking the values I had from part (a) and putting them in columns to make a 3x4 matrix. Then I multiplied that matrix with the vectors in basis B. I feel like this is wrong and I need clarification and proper guidance to do this problem.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: For part (a), you don't need to do any multiplication: the first column of $A$ is the coordinate vector of $T(v_1)$ with respect to $B'$, the second column is the coordinate vector of $T(v_2)$ with respect to $B'$, etc. For part (b), the intention is to think of $T(v_1)$ with respect to the canonical basis. You know $T(v_1)$ is $3w_1+w_2-3w_3$; then you can substitute the definitions of the $w_i$ (which are written with respect to the canonical basis) to get $T(v_1)$ with respect to the canonical basis.

Comment: Ah I see. So for part b, the values on the columns of matrix A corresponds to the coefficient of vectors in the canonical basis. How would one solve part c in this case? Im guessing that since T(2, 2, 0, 0) is equal to T(v1 + v2) which would equal to T(v1) + T(v2) = (3w1 + w2 -3w3) + (-2w1 + 6w2)?